# Shopify Order API - Passing Discount

Tags: shopify

I'm getting some very strange results from Shopify API and I'm hoping someone can help me out.

I'm trying to create an order, with a discount. Its actually saving the order, with the discount information... however the amount is ALWAYS wrong

```
order_params = {
    :browser_ip => webhook[:browser_ip],
    :buyer_accepts_marketing => webhook[:buyer_accepts_marketing],
    :currency => webhook[:currency],
    :email => webhook[:email],
    :financial_status => webhook[:financial_status],
    :landing_site => webhook[:landing_site],
    :note => webhook[:note],
    :referring_site => webhook[:referring_site],
    :line_items => line_items,
    :tag => tags,
    :transactions => transactions,
    :discount_codes => webhook[:discount_codes],
    :total_discounts => webhook[:total_discounts],
    :shipping_address => webhook[:shipping_address],
    :shipping_lines => webhook[:shipping_lines],
    :customer_id => @options[:customer_id],
    :billing_address => webhook[:billing_address]
  }
  @shopify_order = ShopifyAPI::Order.create(order_params)
```

As you can see its created from webhook data. This is giving me back...(truncated)

```
"reference"=>nil,
"user_id"=>nil,
"subtotal_price"=>"55.00",
"total_discounts"=>"55.00",
"location_id"=>nil,
"source_identifier"=>nil,
"source_url"=>nil,
"processed_at"=>"2017-05-31T15:53:03-04:00",
"device_id"=>nil,
"phone"=>nil,
"browser_ip"=>nil,
"landing_site_ref"=>nil,
"order_number"=>1140,
"discount_codes"=>
 [#<ShopifyAPI::Order::DiscountCode:0x007ffbec42ccb0
   @attributes={"code"=>"50% OFF", "amount"=>"55.00", "type"=>""},
   @persisted=true,
   @prefix_options={}>]
```

So far, so good all data is correct.. then I save and this happens.. the amount discounted is incorrect... it should be £55.

[image: shopify error]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't dug too deep into this, but I'm pretty sure the code needs to be unique.

i.e. you probably already have a Discount Code with the same code `50% OFF` with `amount: 60.50` defined somewhere else on that shop.

Try using a new, unique discount code and testing with that.

I would suggest creating a new discount code like `50OFF` that has `amount: 50` with `type: percentage`, then you can re-use that for orders with a 50% discount.

[See the Price Rules reference for more information >](https://help.shopify.com/api/price-rules#tag/Discount-Code)